# Access to data within a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

I have a newbee issue with jQuery... I work in a datatable "aviexptable" and retrive the content of a row throught the following code:

console.log($(aviexptable.rows(value).data()))

Which gives me the following object.

jQuery.fn.init [{…}]
0: {id: 2, plant: "EN", vendor: "89773D", blsid: "BL00002", nbum: 2, …}
length: 1
**proto**: Object(0)

I know try to get the value of the blsid field... But I don't manage to retrieve it. I tried by using a get(), with no success.

Any help welcomed.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please explain more with code & example, what do you need to retrieve? So I can understand your problem more clearly.

Comment: your brackets are not in correct place. $(aviexptable.rows(value).data()) is a jquery object. if you are trying to get data from that, then maybe  $(aviexptable.rows(value)).data() is what you shoud try

Comment: Hello, I think I got the point... I was "chasing" the query and not the object due to the $. The correct, whilst probably not optimized way is the following line: ` console.log(aviexptable.rows(value).data()[0].blsid)`